# Where do I put my callback? (Framework7 Swiper)

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, callback, swiper.js

Im trying to add a callback so on the last image in the swiper it displays an alert, but I'm not sure where to put the callback?

```
 $$(document).on('pageInit', function (e) {
 // Do something here when page loaded and initialized
  var mySwiper = myApp.swiper('.swiper-container',{
 pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
 paginationHide: false,
 autoplay:3000,  
 });                

 })
```

The callback is:
     function onReachEnd(swiper).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Swiper API](http://www.idangero.us/swiper/api/) you add your callbacks right in there with the other parameters, like so:

```
$$(document).on('pageInit', function (e) {
// Do something here when page loaded and initialized
  var mySwiper = myApp.swiper('.swiper-container',{
    pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
    paginationHide: false,
    autoplay:3000,
    onReachEnd: function(swiper) {
      //callback function code here
    }
  });                

})
```

Comment: tried everything so thanks for this it now works perfectly :)